# Limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} \left( 1 - e^{- t} \right)^n$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

The limit ($t \in \mathbb{R}$):

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( 1 - e^{- t} \right)^n $$

according to [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Limit%5B%281-e%5E%28-t%29%29%5En%2C%20n%20-%3E%20%2BInfinity%2C%20Assumptions%20-%3E%20Element%5Bt%2C%20Reals%5D%5D) is zero if $log(1 - cosh(t) + sinh(t)) < 0$. I didn't get why; if I see the step by step solution the result is infinity. Which is a way to get the right result (not in the software, but on a paper)?

[image]

Comment: What is your question ? The limit depend on the value of $t$...

Comment: Set $x = 1-e^{-t}$ and determine $\lim_{n \to \infty}  x^n$ as a function of $x$...

Comment: @Surb what is the right result? In a case Wolfram says $0$, but in the step by step solution is infinity and there is no reference to the condition $log(...)<0$

Comment: @MartinR the result is infinity (link below), but why above is zero? https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Limit%5B%28x%29%5En%2C+n+-%3E+%2BInfinity%2C+Assumptions+-%3E+Element%5Bx%2C+Reals%5D%5D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$x = 1-e^{-t}$ is strictly less than one, so that
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} (1-e^{-t})^n = \lim_{n \to \infty} x^n
$$
exists if and only if
$$
 x > -1 \iff t > -\log(2)
$$
and in that case the limit is zero.

---

The solution from WA can be interpreted as follows: If
$$
\log(1 - \cosh(t) + \sinh(t)) = \log(1-e^{-t})
$$ is negative then
$$
\exp(\infty \cdot \log(1-e^{-t})) = \exp(-\infty) = \lim_{x \to -\infty}e^x = 0 \, .
$$
But that is of limited use because

- it does not cover the case $t\le 0$, where $\log(1-e^{-t})$ is not defined, and
- $\log(1-e^{-t}) < \log(1) = 0$ holds for *all* real $t > 0$.